# Does Delphi provide compiler generated code for simple common operations?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

Sorry if that's a noob question (but I am a Delphi noob).

Let's suppose the following code

**InterfaceUnit.pas**

```
unit InterfaceUnit;

interface

type
    IMyInterface = interface(IInterface)
        procedure DoStuff(withStuff : Stuff);
    end;

    TMyInterfaceHelperClass = class(TInterfacedObject, IMyInterface)
    public
        constructor Create();
        destructor Destroy();
        procedure DoStuff(withStuff : Stuff); virtual; abstract;
    strict protected
        {Have tons of standard ways how to process Stuff}
    end;

implementation
{TMyInterfaceHelperClass}

constructor TMyInterfaceHelperClass.Create();
begin
    inherited Create();
end;

destructor TMyInterfaceHelperClass.Destroy();
begin
    inherited Destroy();
end;

{Have tons of standard ways how to process Stuff implemented here}
end.
```

**ImplementationUnit.pas**

```
unit ImplementationUnit;

interface

uses InterfaceUnit;

type
    TMyInterfaceImplementationClass = class(TMyInterfaceHelperClass)
    public
{*******************************************************************
 * The Question is: ...
 *******************************************************************}
        constructor Create();
        destructor Destroy(); override;
{*******************************************************************}
        procedure DoStuff(withStuff : Stuff); override;
    end;

implementation
{TMyInterfaceImplementationClass}


{*******************************************************************
 * ... Why do I need to write that boilerplate code all the time?
 *******************************************************************}
constructor TMyInterfaceImplementationClass.Create();
begin
    inherited Create();
end;

destructor TMyInterfaceImplementationClass.Destroy();
begin
    inherited Destroy();
end;
{*******************************************************************}

procedure TMyInterfaceImplementationClass.DoStuff(withStuff : Stuff);
begin
     {Combine TMyInterfaceHelperClass to do extraordinary stuff with Stuff}
end;

end.
```

Let's jump out of code and continue with plain text.

As I'm coming from a C++ background, I'm wondering why the compiler can't simply generate the above mentioned boilerplate code pieces?

- Are there particular reasons I miss, why the above mentioned code can't be generated by the compiler in a manner like any decent c++ compiler would do?
- As for the current situation I believe there are macro suites and tools available for RAD Studio (10) to overcome this? (You may post suggestions in comments, because that would be *off-topic* to ask for such tools here).

Comment: "*I'm wondering why the compiler can't simply generate the above mentioned boilerplate code pieces?*" - the IDE has features like [Class Completion](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_Class_Completion) and [Live Templates](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_Live_Templates) that handle these kind of things.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for that. Is it really a good idea to fix (workaround) compiler deficiencies with IDE features? What do you think?

Comment: This is not a compiler deficiency. It is not the compiler's responsibility to *generate* user code in the first place, only to *compile* user code.  *Generating* user code is what an IDE is good for.  All the major IDEs have features relate to that.  You do understand the difference between an IDE and a compiler, don't you?

Comment: @Remy _"You do understand the difference between an IDE and a compiler, don't you? "_ Of course I do, that's why I'm asking?

Comment: @user0042: if you really understood what a *compiler* does and what it is responsible for, you wouldn't need to ask this question at all.  This is not a task for a *compiler* to perform.  No compiler generates code, in any language.

Comment: Nothing can fully 100% automate this, because the IDE has no idea whether you want things to be private, protected, or public.

Comment: @Remy _"This is not a task for a compiler to perform. "_ So the C++ standard comitee went wrong about that?

Comment: @user0042: What C++ *compiler* do you know that generates any kind of boiler plate user code like you described in your question?  NONE, because that is NOT part of the C++ standard.  What you are asking for is something completely different than the compiler generating default implementations of constructors and assignment operators at compile-time. Those implementations are not saved back to user's source code files.

Comment: @user0042: And BTW, in the code you asked about, if you omit the constructor and destructor declarations, they are already inherited from the base class, just like in C++.  In fact, sometimes Delphi does a better job of inheriting constructors than C++ does.

Comment: @Remy Do you want to fool me? Even the MSVC guys got default implementations done for COM interfaces and came up with ATL. Also default (virtual) destructors can be easily generated by the compiler, why do I need to clutter the readability of my code with such boilerplate nonsensical stuff?

Comment: On a side note, boilerplate code is rather common in Delphi. Sure, there are some redundancies which you need to get used to. But it's kinda like switching from an Automatic transmission to a Manual transmission.  Just a quick sample, look at the size of this interface: https://pastebin.com/gLeERHsj Nearly 1,000 lines of code just in the interface section, for something which barely even does too much work.

Comment: @Jerry _Big Size_ vs _Narrow_ Interfaces are an architect's deficiency, not necessarily language designers. All I'm asking for is to eliminate the need for silly IDE workarounds and less readable code, if there's no legal reason, why the compiler can't handle that automatically.

Comment: Refer to my original comment above. There are four general scopes of a class: `private`, `protected`, `public`, and `published`. In your particular example, constructors and destructors always belong in `public`. However, any other methods may reside in a different one. The IDE has no idea which section you want your methods to fall under, therefore you need to instruct it. In C based languages, that was all directly on the definition of the method. However, in Pascal, they get grouped together in the class' definition.

Comment: @Remy _"just like in C++"_ So I don't have to write that _boilerplate code_? If I don't specify the `override` destructor at least, the compiler wil complain.

Comment: @Jerry I'm not actually asking about visibilty. And I'm aware that Delphi just provides 2 cases more, just like latin compared to german.

Comment: @JerryDodge I don't think the OP is talking about class scope visibility nor the IDE, he's talking about the compiler architecture.

Comment: @user0042: if you declare a destructor, then of course you have to declare it as `override`. What I said earlier is if you don't declare the destructor AT ALL, the base destructor is inherited.  Same with constructors.  So, in the code in your question, the only code you actually need is the code related to `DoStuff()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I think that's what I've basically been asking about. Would you mind to scribble that down in a concise answer, so I can accept it and claryfy even other researcher's confusions?

Comment: _@Jerry_ _"However, in Pascal, they get grouped together in the class' definition."_ Wow! What an extraordinary good idea (instead of numbering your structure and function names into a pattern matching scheme in the good old C days).

Comment: Of course I know OP was not speaking about class visibility. I brought that up because "class completion" does not know which scope to put it under, so it typically puts it all under `private`.

Comment: But seeing the answer, and then re-reading the question again, I suddenly understand. I thought you were referring to having to write both an `interface` and `implementation` of all your methods. When actually what you meant was the specific constructor and destructor of an inherited class. Muh bad.

Comment: To be quite honest, it is not clear in your question that the `constructor` and `destructor` in particular are what you are referring to. I thought it was the definition of a method in both the `interface` and `implementation`, and it appears @Remy had the same assumption. I expect someone else to see my confusion here... Meanwhile, voted to close as unclear. If the question's edited to be more clear, I'll retract it :-)

Comment: @JerryDodge my original assumption from reading the question was that he wanted the compiler to actual write the boiler plate code into a source file. Not simply auto-generate default implementation code and link it into the compiled executable.

Comment: While reading the question, in its current state, I get the picture of writing a `constructor` and `destructor` in the `implementation` section, and then using `Class Completion` to auto-generate the method signatures in the class' definition in the `interface`, more than I get a sense of inherited constructors and destructors.

Comment: @user0042: The C++ compiler does not generate boilerplate code like ATL for COM classes. It is the VS IDE which does that (and must do that, often such interfacing code is not necessary in Delphi).

Comment: @user0042: what should the Delphi compiler do that the C++ compiler does? In C++, it is often **necessary** that the compiler generates default, copy and move constructors. That is not necessary in Delphi, so what should the compiler do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a sense, Delphi *already* does what you are asking for.  Just omit the constructor and destructor declarations completely.  When a class derives from another class, it automatically inherits the base class's constructors and destructors unless you `override` them yourself.  In your example, the `override`s are redundant and can be removed.

InterfaceUnit.pas

```
unit InterfaceUnit;

interface

type
  IMyInterface = interface(IInterface)
    procedure DoStuff(withStuff : Stuff);
  end;

  TMyInterfaceHelperClass = class(TInterfacedObject, IMyInterface)
  public
    procedure DoStuff(withStuff : Stuff); virtual; abstract;
  end;

implementation

{TMyInterfaceHelperClass}

end.
```

ImplementationUnit.pas

```
unit ImplementationUnit;

interface

uses InterfaceUnit;

type
  TMyInterfaceImplementationClass = class(TMyInterfaceHelperClass)
  public
    procedure DoStuff(withStuff : Stuff); override;
  end;

implementation

{TMyInterfaceImplementationClass}

procedure TMyInterfaceImplementationClass.DoStuff(withStuff : Stuff);
begin
  {Combine TMyInterfaceHelperClass to do extraordinary stuff with Stuff}
end;

end.
```

Comment: FWIW, there is no need for two classes: `TMyInterfaceHelperClass` and `TMyInterfaceImplementationClass`. Especially a virtual class (`TMyInterfaceHelperClass` is a virtual class) is completely unnecessary. Every class can implement `TMyInterface` by declaring it as such and implementing the methods of the interface. There is no need for some kind of virtual base class.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: in the OP's code, the helper class "has tons of standard ways how to process stuff" that is shared with descendants. I left that part out of the code in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Everything that is declared in an Interface must be implemented by the class.
In your case the Create/Destroy seems to be not necesary to be in an interface.
Every class in Delphi will inherite from TObject which already has a Create/Destroy.

In an interface you should put those functions that will extend the implementor class.

BTW are you putting a Destroy inside Create()?

Comment: I didn't put `constructor` / `destructor` declarations into the interface, read the code again please.

Comment: ops my mistake I din´t read correctly the Interface code, messigng it with the implementation...

Comment: @user0042 You didn't put ctor and dtor in interface type, but you did put them in the class declaration in the interface _section_ of the unit. And as Daniel _correctly_ points out: based on your implementation, the ctor and dtor add **nothing** to your behaviour; they're completely redundant. Simply delete the declaration and implementation. You ***do not need to*** write that boilerplate code _at all_!